# Python code to create 2 threads and as soon as first thread finished execution kill the second thread

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python.

1. I have a stuck with scenario, where i have to create 2 threads, one thread will trigger `method1()`and parallel execute another thread simultaneously(at the same time) which will execute `method2()`.
2. As soon as `method1()` got terminated, it should terminate `method2()` as well.

**Example**

```
import threading
import time

def method1():
    #do something

def method2():
    #do something
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far, what is the output you are getting and what is the expected output. Threads cannot be killed explicitly in Python but you can set a flag from one thread to be checked by the other and have it terminate when the flag is set, for example.